# Depth First Search Random Select Node/Vertex

Tags: java, stack, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I want to find a path to goal from start node using iterative depth first search using this maze represented in graph. It is a text file containing only pair of numbers like a pairwise connection a.k.a edges/arcs. Like this:

```
11 3
2 3
0 3
1 4
5 4
5 7
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
0 5
```

Then my code is like this:

```
private void performIterativeDFS(MazeGraph G, int node, int goal) {
        ArrayBasedStack arrayStack = new ArrayBasedStack();
        ArrayBasedStack pathStack = new ArrayBasedStack();
        arrayStack.push(node);
        visited[node] = true;
        while (!arrayStack.isEmpty()) {
            int newNode = arrayStack.pop();
            if (newNode == 0) {
                out.print("Starting at " + newNode + " ");
            }
            pathStack.push(newNode);
            if (newNode == goal) {
                out.println("Path if goal found: " + pathStack.toString());
            }
            for (int arc : G.getAdjacencyList(newNode)) {
                if (!visited[arc]) {
                    visited[arc] = true;
                    arrayStack.push(arc);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have input 0 as a starting node and goal node is 1. Then the path that output is 0,5,7,8,9,10,6,4,1. Unfortunately, that's not like a proper solution where you can go 0,5,4,1 instead. Does iterative depth first search randomly selects which nodes to go next before reaching the goal?

I tried modifying my code to do that but I can't make the path to print like 0,5,4,1. I want to keep it simple as possible so it is for everyone to understand. Any suggestions or advice?

Comment: You don't use dfs to find shortest path. Use bfs instead

Comment: For those who don't know, BFS stands for Breadth First Search

Comment: I had a breadth-first as well which is fine for me. I just want to know if there is another way of doing that using depth-first search only.

Comment: Are you looking for the shortest path ?

Comment: Basically, Yes. Isn't this optimal for that? Breadth First Search is the best way to find shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a different answer from your search without changing your algorithm(which would not make it a dfs) or (map which would be a waste of time if you were trying to make it for anything besides this specific data set). you could try implementing a sort of backtrace after the code has found a path to reduces the number of nodes traversed, but that wouldn't be the simple answer you're looking for.

Short answer: no, that's not really how DFS works.

EDIT: missed a bit of your question, there's nothing in your code that makes it random. if, rather than

```
for (int arc : G.getAdjacencyList(newNode)) {
            if (!visited[arc]) {
                visited[arc] = true;
                arrayStack.push(arc);
            }
```

you randomly sampled G, then you would have a chance of getting the a different outcome, but as it is there is no random element to it.

Comment: So basically finding a shortest path with dfs is not an optimal solution? Is that right?

Comment: basically. if you are looking for the result, you want a best first algorithm like A*, but if you are focused on the "using DFS" part of your question, there is no way that gets consistent performance without being horribly inefficient

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for that.

Comment: Nothing in my code that makes it random? So the problem was in my iterative algorithm or should I do the recursive? Is this what you mean?

Comment: no, I was just addressing your question about whether dfs was random or not. you used a for loop over your file so it was choosing the next branch based on the file order

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: solution to what? if you mean solution to optimal pathfinding, the answer is still "don't use DFS." If you mean to making your dfs random, then either randomize your map every time you load it in (so the first branch isn't the same every time) or to collect all of a node's branches before adding them to the stack and adding them in random order